# How to send a correct authorization header for basic authentication using guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

How to send a correct authorization header for basic authentication using guzzle

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$username='EFDEMO';
$password='EFDEMO';
$client = new Client(['auth' => [$username, $password]]);
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://mb- 
rewards.calusastorefront.p2motivate.com/client/json.php/ 
getMemberAccount');
$res->getStatusCode();
$response = $res->getBody();
 echo $response;

the error I am getting
{"statusCode":"Error","error": 
{"errorCode":"400","errorMessage":"Authentication Header ID field must 
match Basic Authentication Username"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Referring to documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html?highlight=auth#auth) you should pass the auth parameter in request method instead of client's constructor:

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->request(
    'GET',
    'past-url-here',
    ['auth' => [$username, $password]]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like below

```
<?php
 require '../x_static_libs/guzzle/vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client; 
$client = new Client();

$username = 'xxxxxx';
$password = 'xxxxxxxx';
$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$url = 'https://ervb-rewards.com/client/json.php';

$api_token = 
base64_encode(json_encode(['id'=>'xxxxxxx','token'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']));
```

$res = $client->request(
    'GET',
    $url.'/getMemberAccount',
    ['auth' => [$username,$api_token]]
    );

```
$jsonData = json_decode($res->getBody(), true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($jsonData);
echo "</pre>";
```